# How to use WINDBG debugging tool for debugging?

Tags: c++, com, debugging, remote-debugging

Can any one tell me how to use the WinDbg .

I am created an Application it is works fine in one machine.when i try to run on another machine it fails how can i debug it using windbg.

Comment: What programming language are you using, and is it managed or native code?

Answer (score 8):

Start by downloading WinDbg from:
http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx

You can install it on the target machine, and it will be listed on the Start menu under "Debugging Tools for Windows".

The general idea is to start your application, start WinDbg, attach to your app process, and run under the debugger. Try to provoke the failure and inspect the state of the process with the debugger.

The most common commands are available from the menus, and the help file is excellent for discovering the rest.

Here's a tutorial to get you started:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/windbg_part1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After you install windbg from http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/ you can start debugging your app. Windbg ships with help on commands, so feel free to use it by pressing F1 in the debugger any time.